# VCL Styles with rounded corners

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

Some VCL Styles (Delphi XE2) has rounded corners. How can I change one style for example Metro Blue (not rounded) to rounded ?

Comment: Aren't these styles non-customizable?

Comment: The styles are customizables but I could not change the corners ...